# How to check whether a special field exists in graphql query selection set using resolverInfo?

Tags: graphql

I have a graphql query like this:

```js
query Query {
  edge_feed_posts(first: 15) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        url
        title
        edge_likes(first: 10) {
          count
          edges {
            node {
              id
              percent
              liked_at
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to know whether the field `edges` exists in `edge_likes` or not?

for example something like this:

```js
function edge_likes_resolver(parent, args, context, graph) {
    if (graph.operation.selectionSet.hasField("edges")) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a simple resolver method on the operation to check down the selectionSet chain, but you can do something like

```
const [currentSelections] = operation.selectionSet.selections;
currentSelections.selectionSet.selections.find(
    ({ name }) => name.value === 'edges')
);
```

Comment: Yes, I couldn't find any method to do this and finally I wrote a class with helpful methods to work with graph data. I see you're using `graph.operation` to check selections but I'm using `graph.fieldNodes` which is straight forward to me. do you think I'm in mistake?